# Numbers being added incorrectly for Flash Card game? Cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

I am trying to write code that creates a flash card game. Three players draw 3 cards three times. The card score is the total of cards drawn. However, the card score is being added incorrectly. Example from console:

Player 2 wins with a card score of:85
Cards drawn:
11 2 11
11 3 5
11 13 13

If anyone can help me out or explain a better way to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
void FlashCard::drawCards(FlashCard f[3])
{
    for (int i =0; i<4;++i)
    {
    int a = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 13 + 1;
    f[0].firstDraw[i] = a;
    f[1].firstDraw[i] = b;
    f[2].firstDraw[i] = c;
    }
    for (int i =0; i<4;++i)
    {
    int a = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 13 + 1;
    f[0].secondDraw[i] = a;
    f[1].secondDraw[i] = b;
    f[2].secondDraw[i] = c;
    }
    for (int i =0; i<4;++i)
    {
    int a = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 13 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 13 + 1;
    f[0].thirdDraw[i] = a;
    f[1].thirdDraw[i] = b;
    f[2].thirdDraw[i] = c;
    }
    for (int j = 0;j<3;++j)
    {
    
    for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
            {
            f[j].cardScore += f[j].firstDraw[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
            {
            f[j].cardScore += f[j].secondDraw[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
            {
            f[j].cardScore += f[j].thirdDraw[i];
            }
    }
}
```

This is how I am outputting the winner.

```
void FlashCard::printWinner(FlashCard f[3])
{
    if (f[0].cardScore > f[1].cardScore && f[0].cardScore > f[2].cardScore)
    {
        std::cout << "Player 1 wins with a card score of:" << f[0].cardScore<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "Cards drawn: " << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[0].firstDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[0].secondDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[0].thirdDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    if (f[1].cardScore > f[0].cardScore && f[1].cardScore > f[2].cardScore)
    {
        std::cout << "Player 2 wins with a card score of:" << f[1].cardScore << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Cards drawn: " << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[1].firstDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[1].secondDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[1].thirdDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    if (f[2].cardScore > f[0].cardScore && f[2].cardScore > f[1].cardScore)
    {
        std::cout << "Player 3 wins with a card score of:" << f[2].cardScore << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Cards drawn: " << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[2].firstDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[2].secondDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;++i)
        {
            std::cout << f[2].thirdDraw[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize `f[j].cardScore` with 0 somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in the private part of the class.

Comment: I've added to the question how I am outputting the winner as well.

Comment: If `Three players draw 3 cards three times`, why do you have loops `for (int i =0; i<4;++i)`?

Comment: How large are the `firstDraw`, `secondDraw` and `thirdDraw` arrays?  Everywhere in your code, you're using 3 cards per draw, _except_ where you actually store the random values in which case you're looping as follows: `for (int i =0; i<4;++i)`.  If the arrays only hold 3 values, then you will be overflowing and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I don't know why I had it set to 4. Changing it to 3 worked fine. I feel really dumb but thank you!

Comment: It's best to avoid hard-coded values in your program.  What if you wanted to change the game to allow 4 cards per draw?  It's better to have a constant in your code somewhere (_e.g._ `const int kCardsPerDraw = 3;`) and use that instead.  Same with the player count.  Incidentally, your `printWinner` function duplicates way too much code.  Use a loop (or a standard function like `std::max_element`) to find the winner and condense your code.  Note also that your code does not handle cases where there is a tie.